# Unfortunately,"name application" has stopped

Tags: android

I got some problem from my tutorial that I'm doing from my android book which I've been begining to learn it for a while by android studio program.
I've tired to make application that use ability of SQLite,

But I got this message from "Error log" when I finished my code and try to run it.

```
 11-17 18:05:19.905    1314-1771/? E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa0f86a60
11-17 18:06:07.027    2470-2470/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-17 18:06:07.027    2470-2470/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-17 18:06:07.060    2470-2478/? E/art﹕ Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
11-17 18:06:07.722    2481-2481/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-17 18:06:07.722    2481-2481/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-17 18:06:07.983    2336-2354/? E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabf10560
11-17 18:06:07.997    2490-2490/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "TABLEnotes": syntax error
11-17 18:06:07.998    2490-2490/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote, PID: 2490
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote/com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEnotes": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEnotes(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, timeINTEGER,contentTEXT NOT NULL);
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEnotes": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEnotes(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, timeINTEGER,contentTEXT NOT NULL);
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
            at com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote.NotesHelper.onCreate(NotesHelper.java:25)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
            at com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote.MainActivity.getAllNotes(MainActivity.java:75)
            at com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-17 18:06:08.026      986-986/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 986: eglCreateSyncKHR(1243): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
11-17 18:06:10.260    1314-1771/? E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa0f86a60
```

This is my code :

**- Constants.java**

```
package com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public interface Constants extends BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME   = "notes"; 
    public static final String TIME         = "time"; 
    public static final String CONTENT      = "content"; 
}
```

**- MainActivity.java**

```
package com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Date;

import static com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote.Constants.CONTENT;
import static com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote.Constants.TABLE_NAME;
import static com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote.Constants.TIME;
import static com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote.Constants._ID;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NotesHelper helper;

    private static String[] COLUMNS = { _ID, TIME, CONTENT };
    private static String ORDER_BY = TIME +" DESC";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        helper = new NotesHelper(this); 

        try{
            Cursor cursor = getAllNotes();
            showNotes(cursor);
        }
        finally{

            helper.close();
        }
        final EditText txtNewText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_text);
        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    try{
                        addNote(txtNewText.getText().toString());
                        Cursor cursor = getAllNotes();
                        showNotes(cursor);
                        txtNewText.setText(null);
                    }
                    finally{
                        helper.close();
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addNote(String str){
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(CONTENT,str);
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
    private Cursor getAllNotes(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS, null, null, null, null, ORDER_BY);
        return cursor;
    }
    private void showNotes(Cursor cursor){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Messages has recorded:\n\n");
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            long id = cursor.getLong(0); 
            long time = cursor.getLong(1); 
            String content = cursor.getString(2); 

            builder.append("Number").append(id).append(": ");

            String strDate = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss",new Date(time));
            builder.append(strDate).append("\n");
            builder.append("\t").append(content).append("\n");
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.all_text);
        tv.setText(builder);
    }

}


**- NotesHelper.java**

package com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote;

/**
 * Created by Paradorn on 16/11/2558.
 */
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import static com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote.Constants.CONTENT;
import static com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote.Constants.TABLE_NAME;
import static com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote.Constants.TIME;
import static com.sweetpengiuns.simplenote.Constants._ID;
public class NotesHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="simple_note.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public NotesHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + TIME + "INTEGER,"
                + CONTENT + "TEXT NOT NULL);");

    }

}
```

**- activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dip">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/all_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried to look for some mistake in my code for many times,But I couldn't find it and my programming is not strong.This is my first question to ask you,It seems stupid question,But you can suggest me any things.

Finally,I've found mistake from my coding,it's my stupid.

This code that it makes my app get an error::

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + TIME + "INTEGER,"
                + CONTENT + "TEXT NOT NULL);");

    }
```

Cause I didn't notice in my code whether no space between variable types in SQL command that I wrote.

This code that I fixed it :

```
  @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + TIME + " INTEGER,"
                    + CONTENT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

        }
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace mentioned in the error.

Comment: @PhilippeA Thanks for your suggested,I've already fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

After you are done with your Cursor, you need to close it with this:

```
cursor.close();
```